# How to store dynamically generated ruby has to cassandra using cequel?

Tags: cassandra-2.0, cequel

For example i have a ruby hash with n number of items in it, how do i dyamically store them to cassandra using cequel.

Everytime the hash is going to be different depending upon what activity user is doing.

Comment: CQL supports the `set` and `map` data types. Check out the list of available [data types](http://docs.datastax.com/en//cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/cql_data_types_c.html).